# using paper trail, getting the difference with object_changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using paper trail with Rails 3.1 and would like to get a diff between models. It looks like this is supported by adding object_changes as a text column to versions. I have done this but the changeset is not being saved. Is there any other step that needs to be done?

Comment: how did you get to show the changes from the object_changes? in my case they are all in a string like  "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\ncompany_branch_id:\n- 1\n- 3\ncompany_source_id:\n- 3\n- 2\nclient_category_id:\n- 2\n- 1\nclient_type_id:\n- 2\n" was it like this in your case? if so, how did you render them as attributes on the screen? Thank you.

Comment: your_object_version.changeset will give you a Hash with the changes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to restart your server for paper trail to pick up the change

Comment: +1 - Just ran into this; I can't believe I forgot to restart the server. Thanks for the reminder!